# How to access forgot-password option when you forgot the PIN of your Android Device?

Tags: huawei, emui

I have this [Huawei Nova 3i](https://consumer.huawei.com/ph/support/phones/nova3i/), I forgot the PIN but there's no "forgot password" or "forgot PIN" option. I noticed that my [Huawei Nova 2i](https://consumer.huawei.com/ph/support/phones/nova2i/) doesn't have that option too, and I'm stuck on "Try again after 24 hours".

Normally, when I forgot my password or pin, I just click on the "Forgot Password" option, input the Google Account Password that is bound to the device, and viola, password or pin successfully reset.

Is there a workaround here to use that option?

Comment: google has removed the password option from find my device. i am not sure if that is related to local ROM unlock options, but android is developed by google and i believe that option is no longer available on recent android in general

Answer (score 1):

You can go to google find my android page. Log in to your Gmail account linked with Huawei Nova 3i.

You get 3 option lock / unlock , erase and sound. Use unlock screen option. Now you can access mobile and change passcode. Or take full backup of mobile and restore it.

You can start mobile in recovery mode using volume and power button. Wipe Cache partition. This will remove passcode.

Comment: As @alecxs commented, there is no more option for unlocking your android device on [Google Find My Device](https://www.google.com/android/find). The only options left are `PLAY SOUND`, `SECURE DEVICE`, and  `ERASE DEVICE`.

Comment: Also, wiping cache won't remove the PIN/Password/Pattern, it's not related to security, it's just for cache.